# Mock spliterator for Iterable implementation when called several times?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-stream

I have a problem mocking an `Iterable` class combined with a call of `spliterator()`. It all works fine when calling `spliterator` once, but the second call returns no values.

As the mock always returns the same `Spliterator` instance, I assume that the state is not reset. Is there a way to do this?

This is the smallest example I could give

The call `mapStringToHash` is a Lib in real life and can't be changed.
`MyIterable` is also no object under my control.

```
package net.test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SpliteratorTest {

    class MyIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

        private List<T> list;

        MyIterable(List<T> list) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            return list.iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
            return list.spliterator();
        }
    }

    // this a library method
    private Stream<Integer> mapStringToHash(final MyIterable<String> myIterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(myIterable.spliterator(), false).map(String::hashCode);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSeveralSpliteratorCalls() {
        MyIterable myIterable = givenMyIterableMock("a", "b", "c");

        Stream<Integer> myIterableHash1 = mapStringToHash(myIterable);
        assertThat(myIterableHash1.count(), is(3L));


        Stream<Integer> myIterableHash2 = mapStringToHash(myIterable);
        assertThat(myIterableHash2.count(), is(3L));
    }

    private MyIterable givenMyIterableMock(String... values) {
        MyIterable myIterable = mock(MyIterable.class);

        Spliterator myIterableSpliterator = Arrays.stream(values)
                .collect(toList())
                .spliterator();
        doReturn(myIterableSpliterator).when(myIterable).spliterator();
        return myIterable;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example you gave, I can't see why you'd want to mock `MyIterable` when you could simply create a test instance of it. Should I assume that your real use case truly requires mocking? If yes, the simplest solution would be to extract a method with `givenMyIterableMock("a", "b", "c")` and call this twice (without the `myIterable` variable). As far as I know, Mockito was not designed for the use case you presented (i.e. returning a fresh result every time a mocked method is called). The closest that it comes to this is `AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(Collection)`.

Comment: You are right, MyIterable is not under my control - I updated my question. Maybe there's a way to reset the state of the spliterator?

Comment: Well, `Spliterator`s cannot be reset as such (this is one of the differences between them and `Iterator`s - `Spliterator`s are one-off). The circumvent way to do this would be to implement custom `Answer` that would create the `Spliterator` every time the `answer` method is called, and then call `Mockito.when(myIterable.spliterator()).then(new MyCustomAnswer())`.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a try. You might want to post this as an anwser?

Comment: From [Mockito's Remember section](http://site.mockito.org/#more): [_Do not mock types you don’t own_](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own)

Comment: I'll try not to, but from my point of view sometimes doing so is better than skip testing :)

Comment: It indicates a design issue in your code, as you have a strong dependency on that type. You should wrap it, and mock your wrapper instead. See also https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/Don%27t-mock-what-you-don%27t-own

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski an `Iterator` hasn’t a `reset()` method either. You can fetch a new `Iterator` from an `Iterable`, but that’s not different to fetching a new `Spliterator` from an `Iterable`.

Comment: @Holger You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out! I do know this, but in a rush I must have confused it with PHP's `Iterator`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out it's not as circumvent as I thought. It can be done using a custom `Answer` implementation, but since `Answer` is a functional interface, the following suffices:

```
Mockito.when(myIterable.spliterator()).then(invocation -> Arrays.spliterator(values));
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `when(..).thenReturn(Arrays.spliterator(values))`.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen: This won't work because you're creating only one instance of `Spliterator` instead of an instance per every call (so the second call will return an "empty" `Spliterator`).